# What and how to test in a Presenter with a RxAndroid Use Case

Tags: android, unit-testing, dagger-2, clean-architecture

My project uses [clean architecture](https://github.com/android10/Android-CleanArchitecture).

I use:

- MVP for the presentation layer
- UseCases that use RxAndroid and get DisposableObservers
- Dagger 2 for DI

Sample code from a presenter (Kotlin):

```
fun doSomething() {

    getInterestingDataUseCase.execute(object : DisposableObserver<List<InterestingDataItem>>() {

        override fun onStart() {
            view.showLoadingIndicator()
        }

        override fun onNext(dataList: List<InterestingDataItem>) {
            view.showDataItems(dataList)
        }

        override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
            view.showErrorDialog()
        }

        override fun onComplete() {
            view.hideLoadingIndicator()
        }
    })
}
```

I want to write unit tests for this presenter.

**My question is:** Are the different method calls in the DisposableObserver worth testing (onStart, onNext...)?
And if they are, it looks like I would need to inject the DisposableObserver into the presenter(so that I will be able to mock it). Is there a cleaner way?

Comment: Does TestObserver https://www.infoq.com/articles/Testing-RxJava2 help?

Comment: Thanks, but that is not what I was looking for. I found a solution and answered my own question

Comment: yes you will still have to use mockito for mocking and use TestObserver for testing

Answer (score 1):

Eventually I got to this solution:

- Use [Mockito](https://github.com/mockito/mockito) to mock Objects and responses (as explained [here](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests.html))
- Use [Mockito Kotlin](https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin) to be able to use an any() method that does not show compile time errors when used in Kotlin
- Mock the behavior of the DisposableObserver when the UseCase's execute method is called

Example for a test that checks that the view hides its progress indicator when a request is complete:

```
@Test
fun stopsLoadingStateOnComplete() {

    //given
    given(getInterestingDataUseCase.execute(any())).
            will { invocation ->
                val observer = invocation.arguments[0] as DisposableObserver<List<InterestingDataItem>>
                observer.onComplete()
            }

    //when
    myPreseneter.onReady()

    //then
    then(view).should().hideLoadingIndicator()
}
```